# how to make login for different user and type

Tags: php, html, authentication, system

im doing a system for school which by the user will be admin, teacher and parents. 
im having problem to differentiate two user right now which is admin and parents. 
i cant make sure that admin will directly go to admin.php and parent type will be on parent.php 
any helps will be great! thanks in advance.

and the problem now is that the authentication for the user went wrong if the user enter a wrong username/password, they still can make it to the system.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require("conection/connect.php");

    $msg="";
    if(isset($_POST['btn_log'])){
        $uname=$_POST['unametxt'];
        $pwd=$_POST['pwdtxt'];
        $type=$_POST ['type'];

        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_tbl
                                WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$pwd' AND type='$type'

                            ");

        $cout=mysql_num_rows($sql);
            if (isset($type))
{

    $_SESSION['Parent'] = $type;
    header("location: parent.php");
    }
else {
    $_SESSION['Admin'] = $type;
    header("location: admin.php");
    exit;

}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First don't use `mysql_` it's deprecated.

I assume... $type = `a` means admin and  `p`  means oarent.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$pwd'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($count>0)
{
    if ($type=='p')
    {

        $_SESSION['Parent'] = $type;
        header("location: parent.php");
    }
    elseif($type=='a') {
        $_SESSION['Admin'] = $type;
        header("location: admin.php");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Wrong username or password";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here some solutions. You didn't check if the 'cout' was > 0 (mean found) !

### mysql_ driver

Here a solution with your driver (mysql_) :

```
<?php
session_start();
require("conection/connect.php");

$msg = "";
if(isset($_POST['btn_log'])){
    if(isset($_POST['unametxt'], $_POST['pwdtxt'], $_POST['type'])) {
        $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['unametxt']);
        $pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwdtxt']);
        $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$pwd' AND type = '$type'");  
        $cout = mysql_num_rows($sql);

        if($cout > 0){
            $_SESSION['type'] = $type;

            if($type == "parent")
                header("location: parent.php");
            else if($type == "admin")
                header("location: admin.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

### PDO version

The mysql_ driver is deprecated and you should use PDO instead. So I did the script for PDO driver too :

```
<?php
session_start();
require("connection/connect.php"); // PDO connection on $db variable
$db = connect();

// Function to connect an user
function login($db, $uname, $password){
    $req = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $req->bindParam("username", $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req->bindParam("password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $req->execute();

    $user = $req->fetch();
    if(isset($user['username'])){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user; //store all user datas (including type !)
        return true;
    }

    return false; // fail connection
}


// logic to handle connection form
if(isset($_POST['btn_log'], $_POST['unametxt'], $_POST['pwdtxt'], $_POST['type'])){
    if(login($db, $_POST['unametxt'], $_POST['pwdtxt'])){
        if(isset($_SESSION['user']['type']) AND $_SESSION['user']['type'] == "admin")
            header("location: admin.php");
        else
            header("location: parent.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
        echo "A problem occured !";
}
```

### connect.php (pdo)

```
define("SQL_USER", "root"); // user
define("SQL_HOST", "localhost"); // host
define("SQL_PASS", ""); // password
define("SQL_DBNAME", ""); //db name

function connect(){
    try {
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE] = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;
        return new PDO('mysql:host='.SQL_HOST.'; dbname='.SQL_DBNAME, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, $pdo_options);
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        die("Error connecting to database");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain how to use PDO? because i dont knw how to use PDO for my codings.can i just copy paste your solutions? and put it in connect.php and my index.php?

Comment: Yes you can try my code on a connect.php file and a index.php file. But you have to define values for the database (top of the connect.php).